# How to share Qr code image (QrImageView) with share plus flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I have generated QrImageView in my list view ui and a button to share that generated QrImageView But I am struggling to share it. You will understand from my code

****Code**:**

```
//Function to share asset image
  void onShareXFileFromAssets(BuildContext context) async {
    final box = context.findRenderObject() as RenderBox?;
    final data = await rootBundle.load("assets/images/portraitlogo.png");
    final buffer = data.buffer;

    await Share.shareXFiles(
      [
        XFile.fromData(
          buffer.asUint8List(data.offsetInBytes, data.lengthInBytes),
          name: '',
          mimeType: 'image/png',
        ),
      ],
      sharePositionOrigin: box!.localToGlobal(Offset.zero) & box.size,
    );
  } 

      //In my listView body
          Center(
            child: QrImageView(
              data: widget.groupId,
              version: QrVersions.auto,
              size: 200,
              gapless: false,
            ),
          ),

              IconButton(
                  icon: const Icon(
                    Icons.ios_share_rounded,
                    size: 30,
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    onShareXFileFromAssets(context);
                  })
```

**This is what I got so far. It’s a working example of sharing image from asset And I want to convert it to share QrImageView instead .**

**updated code:**

```
    late Uint8List imageFile;
  ScreenshotController screenshotController = ScreenshotController();

//my ui widget
Screenshot(
              controller: screenshotController,
              child: QrImageView(
                data: widget.groupId,
                version: QrVersions.auto,
                size: 200,
                gapless: false,
              ),
            ),
//Button to screenshot QrImageView widget
    IconButton(
                  icon: const Icon(
                    Icons.ios_share_rounded,
                    size: 30,
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    screenshotController.capture().then((image) {
                      setState(() {
                        imageFile = image!;
                      });
                    })
                  }),

//Button to share Uint8List imageFile
OutlinedButton(
                onPressed: () => Share.shareXFiles([
                  XFile.fromData(
                    imageFile,
                    mimeType: 'image/png',
                  )
                ]),
                style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
                    side:
                        const BorderSide(width: 5.0, color: Colors.transparent),
                    foregroundColor: Colors.transparent),
                child: const Text(
                  'as qr code',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                ),
              ),
```

Comment: see [toImageData](https://pub.dev/documentation/qr_flutter/latest/qr_flutter/QrPainter/toImageData.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [screenshot](https://pub.dev/packages/screenshot) package to convert the `QrImageView` widget into an image. Then you can share it using `Share plus`.

Example:

```
Uint8List _imageFile;

//Create an instance of ScreenshotController
ScreenshotController screenshotController = ScreenshotController(); 

// wrap your widget with the Screenshot widget
Screenshot(
    controller: screenshotController,
    child: QrImageView(...),
),

// take screenshot
screenshotController.capture().then((Uint8List image) {
    //Capture Done
    setState(() {
        _imageFile = image;
    });

    /// share image file
    final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    final imagePath = await 
    File('${directory.path}/image.png').create();
    await imagePath.writeAsBytes(image);

    /// Share Plugin
    await Share.shareXFiles([imagePath.path]);

}).catchError((onError) {
    print(onError);
});
```

Comment: When I captured it and display in the ui it work But when I shared it to others app like IG it's just an black image. How to fix this problem

Comment: can you share your updated code?

Comment: Absolutely I have updated my code above

Comment: I have tried sharing to messenger and Instagram But it’s just an black color image

Comment: the doc shows how to share the captured image too. I have updated the code

Comment: yep I already tried that method too in their doc But the 'shareFiles' is deprecated and shouldn't be used. So I use shareXFiles instead like this `await Share.shareXFiles([XFile(imagePath.path)]);` But still the error still stands.

Comment: can you update the question with the snippet using this approach? Also, please verify if you are getting the image file path and image is being saved

Comment: `Share.shareXFiles([XFile(imagePath.path)])` should be `Share.shareXFiles([imagePath.path])`

Comment: The element type 'Uint8List' can't be assigned to the list type 'XFile'.

Comment: In my answer, you can see that the `imagePath` is actually an image and we are passing its path.